# Adding appearance for hyperref Checkbox

Tags: hyperref

I'm using hyperref to make interactive forms in my PDF's, but I have the problem described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097866/google-chrome-pdf-viewer-checkboxes-are-not-working): when viewed in a browser, the checked checkboxes appear unchecked, though they are checked when the PDF is loaded into a document viewer like evince.

The answer provided on [that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097866/google-chrome-pdf-viewer-checkboxes-are-not-working) says:

> It's likely that the generated PDFs don't have appearances for the check boxes. Without appearances, the viewer doesn't know what to show when the field state changes. How you add the appearances will depend on the library you're using to create the PDF.

**If this is so, how can I set the appearance for hyperref?**

You can see the browser on the left and `evince` on the right.

[image]

Comment: it is an open bug. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/94. The problem is that to repair it quite a large part of the form field code need to be changed and this for all drivers.